# Complete metric space, fixed point and ?reverse? fixed point theorem.

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space, let $F: X\rightarrow X$ such that $$\exists L > 1, \forall (x,y)\in X^2, d(F(x),F(y))>L\cdot d(x,y).$$ Show that if $F(X)=X$ then there is exactly one point $x_0\in X$ such that $F(x_0)=x_0$

I completely don't know how to bite that because it's the exact opposition of the Banach theorem. I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: I think it's rather $\forall_{x,y} \  d(F(x),F(y))\geq L\cdot d(x,y)$, no ?

Comment: @RobertGreen No, it is $>$ but I think it is an error in the textbook.

Comment: What do you mean by "such that $L>1$?" Do you mean that $L$ depends on $x,y$, or that there is some $L>1$ such that $\forall x,y\cdots$

Comment: @Mateusz No, because if you take $x=y$, you get $0 > $ that something positive. So it's $\geq$ indeed, not $>$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I mean that there exists $L>1$ such that for all $x,y$... I am sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Mateusz Np ! So edit your question to correct this, and validate any answer you're happy with ! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

In this case $F$ is injective : if $F(x) = F(y)$ then $0 = d(F(x),F(y) \geq L d(x,y)$ implies that $d(x,y) = 0$, that is, that $x=y$. As $F$ is surjective, it is bijective, and its inverse $F^{-1}$ is Lipschitz with coefficient $1/L < 1$, so as $X$ is complete, this inverse $F^{-1}$ has a fixed point $x_0$, which is also a fixed point for $F$. Finally, this $x_0$ is unique, as $F$ is injective.

Comment: Which is also unique :)

Comment: @Alan That's trivial, as $F$ is a bijection...